# Firebase OnCreate() trigger only fires sometimes

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am setting up a function in firebase with the onCreate trigger in the Real-Time-Database ,but for some reason the onCreate Trigger doesnt always fire .

The Intentions of the script are simple

1. Get the Data of the post and save it in an object
2. Start a function with the object
3. Delete the Realtime Database entry afterwards

This is my function:

```js
exports.onDataAdded = functions.database
    .ref('/')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      try{
      //get the data object in snapshot
      const newValue = snap.data();

      //save it in const
      const data = {
        username : newValue.username,
        password : newValue.password
      }

      //do something
      startProcess(data);

      //Delete the entry
      return snapshot.ref.parent.set(null);
}
      catch(e){
        console.log("error");
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
```

My data looks like this and it adds completely fine into the database:

[image: my realtimedatabase snapshot]

I don't understand why even with the Try and Catch the function only sometimes logs an error ?

Could you please help me here I know that there is a stupid mistake in there

Comment: What exactly is `startProcess`?  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I will also add that setting up a trigger at the root of your database `/` is probably a bad idea, as it **will trigger for every single change** in your database.  That's almost certainly a bad thing.

Comment: Thank you for responding ! I only use the realtime Database for this purpose and I intend to delete every entry afterwards . It is ment as some kind of middle point between user and function . The function calls an API that then makes http requests .

Comment: I understand why you should do that and I now have restructured my database. But is the way I get and delete the data right ?

Comment: @googlefish2 why would you store the data and delete data after your process. Why you don't use firebase rest function instead of trigger?

Comment: Thanks man ! You really helped me ! I now have implemented it and its soooo much easier ! Sorry I'm really new to this